# Email список из txt Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, selenium

Есть скрипт с использованием Selenium, где есть регистрация на разные почты. Есть также .txt файл с почтами (около 16000). Как сделать так, что при каждом новом цикле он брал следующую почту по списку. Спасибо за ответ заранее!

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from auth import username, passw, full_name
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time, random



def login(mail, passw):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\Sh1zik\\Desktop\\Bot\\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get(url="https://eifi.com/register/uJcBF9VvVl")
    time.sleep(random.randrange(2,3))
    email = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Email']")
    email.send_keys(mail)
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1,2))
    name = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Full Name']")
    name.send_keys(full_name)
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1, 3))
    password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Password']")
    password.send_keys(passw)
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1, 3))
    confpassword = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Confirm Password']")
    confpassword.send_keys(passw)
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1, 3))
    confpassword.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(10)
    time.sleep(1000000)



login(mail,passw)
```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, структуру файла с почтами. Как они разделены? В чём конкретно у Вас возникает проблема?

Comment: f.el.exre.gercoin3@gmail.com
fe.l.exre.gercoin3@gmail.com
f.e.l.exre.gercoin3@gmail.com
fele.xre.gercoin3@gmail.com
f.ele.xre.gercoin3@gmail.com
fe.le.xre.gercoin3@gmail.com структура такая @nomnoms12

Comment: Я хочу сделать автоматическую регистрацию. Чтобы использовать каждую почту отдельно. И перебрать весь файл до конца файла. @nomnoms12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предполагая, что почты разделены переводом строки и находятся в файле `mails.txt`, могу посоветовать итерировать файловый объект следующим образом:

```py
with open('mails.txt') as f:
    for mail in f:
        mail.rstrip()
```

Итерирование сильно экономит память — не требуется одновременно хранить все 16000 адресов.

---

Пример того, как можно обернуть скрипт:

```py
def login(mail, passw):
    ...


def main():
    with open('mails.txt') as f:
        for mail in f:
            login(mail, passw)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: А как например скрипт использовал 1 почту. А как сделать чтобы с каждым циклом он использовал все почты поочередно? Просто не понимаю как данный цик реализовать

Comment: @Sh1zik Так вложите Ваш скрипт в цикл. Или вынесите его в отдельную функцию/класс и в этом цикле вызывайте. Привёл пример

Comment: Простите за банальные вопросы, но как можно было бы ответ поместить в одну переменную чтобы использовать в скрипте?

Comment: @Sh1zik Я не знаю, как выглядит Ваш скрипт. Можете привести его в вопрос?

Comment: Уже есть скрипт в вопросе. (он пока в стадии разработки, поэтому некоторые функции нелогичные)

Comment: @Sh1zik Обновил пример. Допишите только тело функции `login` и импорты.

Comment: А есть возможность связаться вне форума? Если у Вас будет время @nomnoms12

Comment: @Sh1zik Смотря для чего. Если это связано с вопросами о программировании, то я отвечаю в свободное время только на StackOverlow. Если комментарии слишком ограничены для нашего диалога, то я могу создать отдельный чат

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from auth import username, passw, full_name
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time, random

password = "qwerty123"



def login(mail, passw):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\Sh1zik\\Desktop\\Bot\\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get(url="https://eifi.com/register/uJcBF9VvVl")
    time.sleep(random.randrange(2,3))
    email = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Email']")
    email.send_keys(mail)
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1,2))
    name = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Full Name']")
    name.send_keys(full_name)
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1, 3))
    password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Password']")
    password.send_keys(passw)
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1, 3))
    confpassword = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Confirm Password']")
    confpassword.send_keys(passw)
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1, 3))
    confpassword.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(10)

file = open("account.txt").read()
for i in file.split("<Сюда вставить символ которым разделяется аккаунты, если каждая почта с новой строки \n>"):
    login(i,password)
```

Как я понимаю вам нужен такой цикл. Подучите основы Python.

Comment: Спасибо за решение

Comment: @Sh1zik Если ответ решил вашу проблему поставьте галочку слева от ответа, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Sh1zik Изменил под новый вопрос

Comment: Извиняюсь не указал пароль статичен.

Comment: Теперь настроено под статичный пароль.